# Checking Event in solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, simulation, numerical-methods

**What is a fast way of checking which event has been triggered in scipy.solve_ivp()?**
For context, I am simulating a double pendulum. I want to check if either the first rod or the second rod has been flipped. I have created two event functions for each, but once the event is triggered, is there any way I can retrieve which event has been triggered? Thanks :)

Comment: If you let it terminate the integration, yes. If that's not what you want to do, please indicate what you wanted to do with that information (e.g. change equations of motion?).

Comment: Yes, after the event has been triggered, I terminate the integration. I want to know which event has been triggered (event_a or event_b).

Comment: In the result object, `t_event` contains a list of times at which each event occurred. The position of the array containing the maximum time indicates which event occurred. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html if that is not enough, post a minimal reproducible example to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I see there's an answer. Might as well post, since it's already written:

There are two terminal events in the following code, which represents a simple harmonic oscilator.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def dy(t, y):
    return [y[1], -y[0]]

def event1(t, y):
    return y[0]
event1.terminal = True

def event2(t, y):
    return y[1]
event2.terminal = True

tspan = [0, 10]
y0 = [0.1, -0.1]
sol = integrate.solve_ivp(dy, tspan, y0, events=[event1, event2])
```

According to the [`solve_ivp` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), `sol.t_events` is a list of arrays of times at which an event occured. The first array in the list corresponds with the first event; the second array corresponds with the second event. In case some of the events are non-terminal, create a list with time of the *last* event in each array:

```py
last_events = [(t_event[-1] if len(t_event) else tspan[0]) for t_event in sol.t_events]
```

The event which occured is the `argmax` of these.

```py
np.argmax(last_events)  # 0
```

In this case, the first event (event 0) occured, which means that the "position" `y[0]` has crossed zero. You can change the initial "velocity" to `y0[1] = -y0[1]` to see that the [argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) becomes `1`, so the second event (event 1) occurs, which means that the velocity has crossed zero.

Comment: You should contemplate if you need the events to be terminal. Usually that is only useful if you change the model phase or introduce some jump in the state. Otherwise let the integration run for some while and then work the event arrays with their registered events.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass multiple events to `solve_ivp`, the return value `sol.t_events` and `sol.y_events` indicates which kind of event happened by putting different events in different arrays.

Here's an example, which I have [adapted from the SciPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). I am simulating a cannon being fired, and I want to know both when the cannonball reaches its peak, and when the cannonball hits the ground.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def upward_cannon(t, y):
    return [y[1], -0.5]

def hit_ground(t, y):
    return y[0]

def peak(t, y):
    return y[1]


hit_ground.terminal = True
hit_ground.direction = -1


events = [peak, hit_ground]
sol = solve_ivp(upward_cannon, [0, 101], [0, 10], events=events)
print(sol.t_events)
```

Output:

```
[array([20.]), array([40.])]
```

Here, the first element in `events` is `peak()`. Because of that, the first element of `sol.t_events` is an array of t values where that event occurred.  That value is `array([20.])`, so it happened only once, at t = 20. The second array corresponds to the second set of events.

The `sol.y_events` return value is similar.